# I have some problems with fopen() for c-string

Tags: c++, file, file-io, stream, c-strings

I have a file name stored as c-string. I need to open the file and count lines in it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char str[] = "myfile.txt";
  FILE* file = fopen(str, "r");
  int counter = 0, ch = 0;
  while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(file)))
    if (ch == '\n')
      ++counter;
  fclose(file);
  printf("%d", counter);
  return 0;
}
```

evrething works just fine if I use `fopen("myfile.txt", "r")` insted. How to make it work with a c-string file name.

Comment: What is a "c-string"? Do you mean an `std::string`? Or what error are you seeing? Also, your code is not `c`, so I have removed that tag.

Comment: Typo ? `fopen("myfile", "r")` vs `"myfile.txt";`

Comment: @KenY-N C-string (or C-style string) for C++ devs means null terminated `char[]` or `char*`. They are called like that to distinguish them from `std::string`. Same for C-style arrays.

Comment: This code runs fine (except for the subtle 'last newline' problem). You are probably making some other trivial error like what @RichardCritten mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please `use string.c_str()`

```
int main() {
  string path = "myfile.txt";
  FILE* file = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
  int counter = 0, ch = 0;
  while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(file)))
    if (ch == '\n')
      ++counter;
  fclose(file);
  printf("%d", counter);
  return 0;
}
```